# Question Answer and Problem Answer document

Tags: sectioning, answers

In the code below, there are two parts in the document.  The first part contains a Question then Answer, and the second part contains a Problem then Answer.

For Part 1, I wanted to format the document such that it will appear like:

Question 1

Q1 Question 1

...

AQ1 Answer 1

...

Question 2

Q2 Question 2

...

AQ2 Answer 2

...

Then for Part 2, the format should appear like:

Problem 1

P1 Problem 1

...

AP1 Answer 1

...

Problem 2

P2 Problem 2

...

AP2 Answer 2

...

Here is the code that is written thus far:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=3.2cm,right=3.2cm,headsep=10pt,letterpaper]{geometry}
\usepackage{rotating, ltablex, dcolumn}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable}

\usepackage{titletoc}

\begin{document}

\mainmatter

\part{Questions}
\chapter{Question 1}
\section{Question 1 }
\section{Answer 1 }
\chapter{Question 2}
\section{Question 2 }
\section{Answer 2 }
\chapter{Question 3}
\section{Question 3}
\section{Answer 3}
\chapter{Question 4}
\section{Question 4}
\section{Answer 4}
\chapter{Question 5}
\section{Question 5}
\section{Answer 5}
\chapter{Question 6}
\section{Question 6}
\section{Answer 6}
\chapter{Question 7}
\section{Question 7}
\section{Answer 7}

\part{Problems}
\chapter{Problem 1}
\section{Problem 1}
\section{Answer 1}
\chapter{Problem 2}
\section{Problem 2}
\section{Answer 2}
\chapter{Problem 3}
\section{Problem 3}
\section{Answer 3}
\chapter{Problem 4}
\section{Problem 4}
\section{Answer 4}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is your code minimal?

Comment: IMHO this is the job of enumerate not sectionning see [enumitem](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This uses a switch for the individual styles, `\questionanswer` for the first part and `\problemanswer` for the 2nd part.

The `\if@questionmode` checks whether the current `section` is the question or the answer -- no gaps between questions are assumed!

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=3.2cm,right=3.2cm,headsep=10pt,letterpaper]{geometry}
\usepackage{rotating, ltablex, dcolumn}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable}

\usepackage{titletoc}% 

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithout{section}{chapter}
\counterwithin{section}{part}

\makeatletter
\let\latex@@thesection\thesection
\newif\if@questionmode

\newif\if@problemanswermode

\newcommand{\problemprefix}{P}
\newcommand{\problemanswerprefix}{A\problemprefix}
\newcommand{\questionprefix}{Q}
\newcommand{\questionanswerprefix}{A\questionprefix}


\DeclareRobustCommand{\questionanswerformat}{%
    \if@questionmode%
    \questionprefix\arabic{section}%
    \global\@questionmodefalse
    \else
    \addtocounter{section}{-1}%
    \questionanswerprefix\arabic{section}%
    \global\@questionmodetrue
    \fi
}


\DeclareRobustCommand{\problemanswerformat}{%
    \if@questionmode%
    \problemprefix\arabic{section}%
    \global\@questionmodefalse
    \else
    \addtocounter{section}{-1}%
    \problemanswerprefix\arabic{section}%
    \global\@questionmodetrue
    \fi
}

\newcommand{\questionanswer}{%
  \@questionmodetrue
  \renewcommand{\thesection}{%
    \questionanswerformat%
  }%
}

\newcommand{\problemanswer}{%
  \@questionmodetrue
  \renewcommand{\thesection}{%
    \problemanswerformat%
  }%
}

\makeatother

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\part{Questions}
\questionanswer
\chapter{Question 1}
\section{Question 1 }
\section{Answer 1 }
\chapter{Question 2}
\section{Question 2 }
\section{Answer 2 }
\chapter{Question 3}
\section{Question 3}
\section{Answer 3}
\chapter{Question 4}
\section{Question 4}
\section{Answer 4}
\chapter{Question 5}
\section{Question 5}
\section{Answer 5}
\chapter{Question 6}
\section{Question 6}
\section{Answer 6}
\chapter{Question 7}
\section{Question 7}
\section{Answer 7}

\part{Problems}
\problemanswer
\chapter{Problem 1}
\section{Problem 1}
\section{Answer 1}
\chapter{Problem 2}
\section{Problem 2}
\section{Answer 2}
\chapter{Problem 3}
\section{Problem 3}
\section{Answer 3}
\chapter{Problem 4}
\section{Problem 4}
\section{Answer 4}

\end{document}
```